# Interpolation of a logarithmic function

Tags: logarithms, interpolation

I have a logarithmic function

$$m \ln(x) + b$$

And three points

$$(x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$$

The task is to find $m$ and $b$.

Do I understand right that the third point is redundant?
Because

$$\begin{cases} 
m \ln(x_0) + b = y_0 \\
m \ln(x_1) + b = y_1 
\end{cases}$$

Therefore

$$ y_0 - y_1 = m(\ln(x_0) - \ln(x_1)), $$
$$m = \frac{y_0 - y_1}{\ln(x_0) - \ln(x_1)}$$

and $b$ is found trivially from either equation.

Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: Are you sure that the task is _interpolation_ and not _regression_?

Comment: The task is just "find". 

And I may obviously interpolate and I may obviously min-square. But in the case of interpolation I only need two points, don't I?

Comment: Yes for interpolation you need two points with $x_0 \ne x_1$.  A third point is in the best case redundant, but in almost all cases it make the task insolvable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two parameters and three equations, the system is overdetermined and you can use the method of least squares, see this question I asked for the method using the transpose of the matrix.

[Is the least squares solution to an overdetermined system a triangle center?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471812/is-the-least-squares-solution-to-an-overdetermined-system-a-triangle-center)